# GeoTIFF Layer Preview with Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geotiff

I need help with serving GeoTIFF Image on Geoserver.

I only got a blank layer preview on OpenLayers and an invalid image in PNG format. I followed this [guide](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_geotiff.html) on how to add the GeoTIFF image. It only loads the bounding box extent but with no image like the picture below [image: blank_image],

This is the log file, when I requested layer preview using OpenLayer :

```
Request: getMap
Angle = 0.0
BaseUrl = http://172.105.126.51:8081/geoserver/
Bbox = SRSEnvelope[680086.6381284555 : 680897.2906084555, 9124213.379031269 : 9124973.017911268]
BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
Buffer = 0
CQLFilter = null
Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 49S", 
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", 111.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 10000000.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32749"]]
Elevation = []
Env = {}
Exceptions = SE_XML
FeatureId = null
FeatureVersion = null
Filter = null
Filters = null
Format = application/openlayers
FormatOptions = {}
Get = true
Height = 719
Interpolations = []
Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@e35cd445]
MaxFeatures = null
Palette = null
RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:32749, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=680086.6381284555,9124213.379031269,680897.2906084555,9124973.017911268, VERSION=1.1.0, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=768, HEIGHT=719, LAYERS=raster_matra:orto_matra_udara}
RemoteOwsType = null
RemoteOwsURL = null
Request = GetMap
RequestCharset = UTF-8
ScaleMethod = null
Sld = null
SldBody = null
SldVersion = null
SortBy = null
SortByArrays = null
SRS = EPSG:32749
StartIndex = null
StyleBody = null
StyleFormat = sld
Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=raster]]
StyleUrl = null
StyleVersion = null
Tiled = false
TilesOrigin = null
Time = []
Transparent = false
ValidateSchema = false
Version = 1.1.0
ViewParams = null
Width = 768
```

I also provided the way I added the image :

1. I created a new workspace
   [image]
2. Then created a new store
   [image]
3. Published layer (mostly I left everything by default)
   [image]
   [image]

This is the GeoTIFF image that I want to serve using Geoserver

[image: original]

I run gdalinfo on the image :

[image]
[image]

What do you think ?

I do appreciate any help, thanks

Regards,

Yogi

Comment: please add the output from `gdalinfo` for the image and more details of how you added the image to geoserver.

Comment: I've edited and provided more details on my question. Thanks

Comment: please run `gdalinfo` on the image and add the contents of the bad png file (it's an XML error message)

Comment: looks good so far - please check for the actual error in the logs or the returned "image"

Comment: sorry, @IanTurton I give the wrong log file. I've updated the log file again